# Installation directory linux not working?

Tags: linux, tkinter, terminal, directory

I'm really new to Linux and it's terminal, so this is most likely a stupid question, but I'm really really stuck.

I'm trying to install Tk, and everything was going fine until I get:

> Please specify the installation directory.
>
> Path [/opt/ActiveTcl-8.6]:

And it seems like whatever I fill in I get the error that I can't create that director, what do I need to fill in? What are they asking for? Because when I'm give them an existing folder it gives me an error and when I give a random name it gives an error. I'm getting so confused.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using an account with write permissions on the installation directory? Do you execute the installation as root or with sudo?

Comment: as root, I'm using a supercomputer so I don't have permission for sudo

Comment: If you use `root` user, you don't need to use `sudo`.  Does `/opt` directory exist?

Comment: No the /opt directory doesn't exist

Comment: So try to create the `/opt` directory first, then re-run the installation again.

Comment: but how? The read me document of the thing I try to install says that it will create this path?